# How to compare data from one variable with a subset of another variable in R

Tags: r

I'm working with two variables "Neighbourhood" and "UtilitySpending". The first is a nominal variable where all records are either "city", "town", or "rural". The second is a continuous variable which is just the amount a given household spends on utilities in a month (varying anywhere from between $500 to $6000 in the dataset).

My issue is that using these two variables, I want to find the mean of the utility spending of all the records which are in a "city" in the Neighbourhood variable, so as to conduct a z-test to see if it differs significantly from the mean of the whole dataset. I'm sure there is a command I can use, but I haven't been able to find one to isolate the mean. What's the best way to find this information, given I have 3000 records to sift through?

I want to find the mean of UtilitySpending for all those records which have a "city" as their Neighbourhood value. How can I do this?

Comment: `aggregate(UtilitySpending, list(Neighbourhood), mean)`

Answer (score 0):

Using dplyr package:

```
library(dplyr)

dt<-data.frame(Neighbourhood=c("city","rural","town","city","rural"),UtilitySpending=c(500,753,438,3361,4717))

dt<-dt %>% group_by(Neighbourhood) %>%
           dplyr::summarize(total_UtilitySpending=mean(UtilitySpending)) %>%
           as.data.frame() %>%
           filter(Neighbourhood=="city")
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done in base R in one line. Since you didn't provide data, I'm re-using a set from a previous question, see below.

With this data.frame, you can find any mean etc. with subsetting. Here the example to calculate the mean of column `Urgent` whenever the variable `YPred` is equal to `L2`:

```
mean( df[ df$YPred == "L2", "Urgent" ] )
[1] 44
```

Below the sample data:

```
    df <- structure(list(Tag = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L
), YPred = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L
), .Label = c("L1", "L2", "L3", "L4", "L5"), class = "factor"), 
    Long = c(1004L, 544L, 545L, 282L, 1L, 2068L, 3006L, 3711L, 
    2342L, 33L), Medium = c(108L, 252L, 211L, 149L, 0L, 17L, 
    110L, 248L, 341L, 4L), short = c(58L, 118L, 131L, 73L, 4L, 
    0L, 43L, 150L, 189L, 2L), Urgent = c(5L, 70L, 65L, 24L, 5L, 
    22L, 18L, 31L, 96L, 2L)), .Names = c("Tag", "YPred", "Long", 
"Medium", "short", "Urgent"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help vaettchen. The only thing I would note about your line of code after testing is that for non-numerical searches (e.g. L2) I had to use speech marks otherwise I received an error, namely: 
mean( df[ df$YPred == "L2", "Urgent" ] )